# Cosmos provider for Entity Framework Core creating container with DbContext class name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB in asp net core 3.1 app with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos package. In my AppContext class on OnModelCreating method i've give every dbset ToContainer() method to define the name of container otherwise it'll give AppContext name to container. Everything is working fine but it still create one container AppContext in CosmosDb, how can i fix this? Please help. Below is my code.

AppContext Class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CosmosApp.Context
{
    public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        public AppContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToContainer("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().ToContainer("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToContainer("UserRoles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToContainer("UserLogins");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToContainer("UserClaims");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToContainer("Roles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToContainer("UserTokens");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().ToContainer("Teachers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToContainer("Students");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasNoDiscriminator();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasNoDiscriminator();
        }
    }
}
```

AppUser Class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CosmosApp.Entities
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Startup Class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseCosmos(
                    "https://localhost:8081/",
                    "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
                    "TestDb");
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options => { })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication();
        }
```

Program Class

```
using System;
using CosmosApp.Context;
using CosmosApp.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using AppContext = CosmosApp.Context.AppContext;

namespace CosmosApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppContext>();
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
                    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                    Seed.SeedData(context, userManager, roleManager).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration");
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Packages Info

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now you can see it was creating unknown conatiner AppContext
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [HasDefaultContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.CosmosModelBuilderExtensions.HasDefaultContainer?view=efcore-3.1) for the first Entity and `ToContainer` on subsuquent Entities.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder builder ) {
     builder.HasDefaultContainer("Users");
     builder.Entity<User>().ToContainer("Users");
     builder.Entity<Teacher>().ToContainer("Teachers");
     builder.Entity<Student>().ToContainer("Students");

 }
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. I've accept your answer. One more question how can i change the name of columns? and give order to columns?

Comment: I'm working through that myself, if I find the answer, I'll update this.

Comment: OK Thanks Derek Beattie.